# Keep a session active on page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, session, token

I've just taken over a code base and the previous dev did not use cookies or localstorage to store the token. I'm wondering how, if i send the token the to client and store it in localstorage, I can then use that to persist the session when the user hits refresh. How can I implement this?

Comment: Session should be maintained on the server.

Comment: How can i do that without storing the session in my database?

Comment: You can use an 'in memory' session.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to use LocalStorage. As I assume you somehow have a connection between the users token and the session on the server side.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You can store everything you want in there, but I would not store any sensitive information...

```js
var ls = window.localStorage;

ls.setItem("token", "someTokenYo");

console.log(ls.getItem("token"));
```

You cannot use the localStorage in the Snippet because of sandboxing. But with the token at hand you should manage to do whatever you want easily. Due to the lack of  details this is the only thing I can provide.

Comment: I think what you are assuming is what I am missing. If I have the token stored on the front end, how can I check that from the back end so that when the page refreshes it keeps the user's context?

Comment: You need to make the correct responses to your server and aquire the data, or you store all relevant data in the localStorage (not recommended). That is the whole point for a token or let's call it sessionId. But that is an implementation detail you need to find in your -- I assume -- NodeJS application. If you provide some Information at least, I wouldn't need to give you this broad and vague answer.

Comment: Thanks for the dialogue. I'm struggling to provide relevant information because I am very unfamiliar with authroization and I'm not sure what i can tell you that is relevant. Ive got a react app using node on the back end. We are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken to generate our web token and they are not being persisted in any kind of local storage anywhere. Thank you again for the dialogue. please help me provide you with any information you might find relevant to help me solve this problem.

Comment: I don't want to offend you, but you should get a basic understanding of state of the art web-technologies. Including OAuth (or whatever Protocol you are using with JWT) and how it is used to find out how and where the data is aquired inside your front end (I assume some kind of http calls against your Backend which is an REST Architecture?). State these details in your question please.

Comment: If you are into WebDeveloping, maybe it may help to use the Browsers Dev-Tools and take a look into the Request made on the main page and then work your way further into that.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    body.onload = function() {
    /* 
       check if the session exists in cookie or localStorage
       if does, save that information into a variable for further coding, 
       something like:

       const isAuthenticated = true
    */  
    }
})();
```